# load follow list from instagram using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, instagram

I want to get an Instagram follower list using jQuery, I am using the following code, but it is not working. What should I do?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/follows?",
    dataType: 'GET',
    data: { access_token: token },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.meta.code);
        alert(result.data.username);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Also you should add `dataType: 'json'` to your code if the answer you're expecting is `json`

Comment: Following error comes when I run it.
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/follows?&access_token=1281148571.506af84.f3f6cfcagg9feb6287f77e7a01gfga5b2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://instafollow.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: alert("error"); execute when this code run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try is like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/follows?",
    type: 'GET', // type instead of dataType
    dataType: 'json', // or jsonp for cross-domain 
    data: {
        access_token: token
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.meta.code);
        alert(result.data.username);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: deprecated and removed from instagram api, is there any workaround to get list of followers or follows with userID not self ?